# How can I deploy Asp.Net MVC 2 Beta in IIS6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I am getting 403 error when publish an Asp.Net MVC app to IIS6. Any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a walkthrough on deploying ASP.NET MVC to IIS 6 here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Just curious, the write up was targeting MVC 1, I'm assuming MVC 2 can be deployed in the same manner?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of resources out there. [Here](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) is one of them about mvc and iis 6